# Query regarding recommended implementation for single sign on

Tags: openid-connect, saml-2.0, google-identity

So I have been trying to figure out how to build a b2b integration to allow Single sign on with google .
With microsoft we managed to pull it off with open id connect [ considering its the shiny new standard and support from ms was pretty good ] .

With google, I acquired a workspace account which would represent our target users but it seems to only support saml based apps out of the box. Now , for open id I see 2 options with the developer account -

1. one can go ahead and follow these steps so that every user can register their own apps and thus allow something like microsoft's multi tenant open id . But this involved a decent effort on each clients end. Also we would now need to identify tenants initially to be able to correctly redirect [with microsoft this is not needed because of their common/organisation tenants ]  -
   https://www.firezone.dev/docs/authenticate/oidc/google
2. Create an app and publish it from your google dev account . But it seems more oriented towards B2C use cases. Also the admin of a workspace account won't be able to monitor logins via google if they wish to do so .

Google does seem to offer multi tenant but it seems to be pretty manual and unless I am missing something here , unlike microsoft's enpterprise application / service principal doesnt give the control back to the client's . It'll have to be managed by us including the 2fa / sms verification if required by some clients.

So , is the best way right now saml for b2b use cases if I want to integrate google right now ? Has anybody tried openid with google and succeded with minimal overhead to end users ?